# find spans containing mix of numbers and text and get sum of second number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on an addon for a simple html game. In one part of it I'd like to display a total of the upkeep of a players abilities. Currently they display on each ability and I thought it would be nice to have my addon show a total at the top of the page. The elements look like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 text-center" style="padding-top: 10px;">
   <p style="background-color: red;">
      <b>Upkeep: </b>31 Bux each<br>1798 Bux total</p>
</div>
```

I've added a line that turns the span background red just so I could see that I was at least grabbing the right elements. So far my code is returning NaN. Here is my code:

```
var sumdtotal = 0;
    $('div[class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 text-center"] p').each(function() {
    var value = $(this).text().replace(" Bux each", "").replace(" Bux total", "");
    sumdtotal += +value;
    $(this).css( "background-color", "red" );
    });
    $("#totalupkeep").text(sumdtotal);
```

The idea is to display the total upkeep in the span #totalupkeep.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to get just the numbers.  You dont have an element with ID totalupkeep so I'm not sure how you want to display it.  I'm also not completely clear what calculations you're trying to make.  Hopefully this helps:

```
$('div[class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 text-center"] p').each(function() {
  var value = $(this).text().match( /\d+/g )
  $(this).css( "background-color", "red" );
  $("#totalupkeep").text('' + value[1]);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gf1rcqoy/3/

EDIT: Value is an array with both numbers in it.  The first value is each, the second is total.

Comment: It is a Chrome extension which I provide for free (I play the game too). I'm trying to scan for and then provide a total of the upkeep for all abilities on the page. Players can buy and sell abilities so they won't always be the same. Right now your provided code is displaying "undefined" for the Total Upkeep.

Comment: @ShcFinalJudgement can you show all of your code?  I'm getting 1798 when I log value[1].  I have know idea what your markup looks like for #totalupkeep.

Comment: #totalupkeep is a span injected into the page by one of the other js files that make up the Chrome extension.
    `<span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Total Upkeep:&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="totalupkeep"></span>`

Comment: @ShcFinalJudgement I updated the fiddle and it works for me, as far as I understand it: https://jsfiddle.net/gf1rcqoy/3/

Comment: There are multiple divs containing different values. Wouldn't I need to convert value into an integer? Is it because the script is still treating it like text that instead it displays "undefined"?

Comment: This take on using your code returns all of the numbered values separated by commas rather than a total:
`var sumdtotal = 0;
  $('div[class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 text-center"] p').each(function() {
  sumdtotal += $(this).text().match( /\d+/g );
  $(this).css( "background-color", "red" );
  });
  $("#totalupkeep").text(sumdtotal);`